# Image not getting upload in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am uploading an image using the following php code but the file is not getting upload.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $title = $_POST['title'];

    $target_folder = "../newsimageuploads/";
    $bannerimagelink = "http://example.com/newsimageuploads";

    $bannerimage = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['bannerimage']['tmp_name']));
    $bannerimage_name = addslashes($_FILES['bannerimage']['name']);
    $bannerimage_size = getimagesize($_FILES['bannerimage']['tmp_name']);

    if ($bannerimage!=""){

    $rand = rand(111111, 9999999);
    $fname =  $_FILES["bannerimage"]["name"];
    $newname = "Image ".$rand.".png";

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["bannerimage"]["tmp_name"], $target_folder.$newname);
    $bannerimage_location = $bannerimagelink."/".$newname;
    } 

    $query =mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (title,image) VALUES ('$title','$bannerimage_location')")or die(mysql_error());
    if (($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:green;'>Added Successfully</p>";
    } else {
    echo "Some Error Occured :(";
    }
}
```

And my HTML part is

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="file" name="bannerimage" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

My title is getting insert in the MySQL table but image does not.

Comment: I guess you should pass the image as a blob rather than passing a file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

to the form tag. Without this attribute you will only get the name of the file. But the file itself won't be uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="title">
<input type="file" name="bannerimage" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif">
<button type="submit" name="submit">Add</button>
```